# Does Shannon Entropy uniquely characterise distribution function $f$?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, entropy, information-theory

If I have a distribution $f(x)$ over the real line where the support is the whole line, does the Shannon Entropy  uniquely characterise $f$? I.e., do we have $H(f) = H(f^*)$ implies $f = f^*$?  (The reverse is obviously true.)

Comment: You have a good answer provided, if you're ok with it, can you please accept and/or upvote it? And, just a marginal example: let your RV be a constant, e.g. X=2 or X=3. The distribution is different, but for both the entropy is $0$.

Comment: Thank you so much for remind me upvote. I am happy with both of answers.

Comment: You can also click the gray tick under the arrow in the answer to accept the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is in the negative.  For any real number $a$ define the function

$$f_a(x) = f(x-a).$$

It is clear that when $f$ is a distribution function, so is $f_a;$ that when $f$ is supported on the real line, so is $f_a;$ and that [both $f$ and $f_a$ have equal entropy.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/415435)  For $a\ne 0$ it is impossible that $f=f_a,$ though, for if so, $f$ would be periodic with period $a$ and therefore the total probability would either be zero or infinite, which is not possible for any probability distribution.

Comment: Thank you so much, it is great