# Laplace and Normal Distribution Cross Entropy

Tags: expected-value, kullback-leibler, integral, cross-entropy, laplace-distribution

I need the following integral and struggle with calculating it or finding a citable source.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(x-\mu)^2\exp\!\left(-\frac{|x-\nu|}{\tau}\right)dx.$$

Background: I want to find an expression for the KL-Divergence from a Gaussian density $f()$ to a Laplace density $g(),$ i.e. $\mathbb{E}_g[\log g(x)]-\mathbb{E}_g[\log f(x)]$. I have done the first expectation, with user whuber's trick and([KL Divergence Normal and Laplace densities](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/474347/kl-divergence-normal-and-laplace-densities)) and brute force. The trick, however doesnt apply for the second expectation, whose hardest part is the integral in the question.

Comment: Hint: recall that$$\mathbb{E}[(X-\mu)^2]=\text{var}(X)+(\mathbb{E}[X]-\mu)^2$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming $\tau>0,$ let $\xi=x-\mu$ and $\lambda=\nu-\mu.$ Then $dx=d\xi,$ and we have
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(x-\mu)^2 e^{-|x-\nu|/\tau}\,dx
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\xi^2 e^{-|\xi+\mu-\nu|/\tau}\,d\xi\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\xi^2 e^{-|\xi-\lambda|/\tau}\,d\xi\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\lambda \xi^2 e^{(\xi-\lambda)/\tau}\,d\xi
+\int_\lambda^\infty \xi^2 e^{-(\xi-\lambda)/\tau}\,d\xi\\
&=\left[e^{(\xi-\lambda)/\tau}\tau\left(2\tau^2-2\tau\xi+\xi^2\right)\right]_{-\infty}^{\lambda}\\
&\quad-\left[e^{-(\xi-\lambda)/\tau}\tau\left(2\tau^2+2\tau\xi+\xi^2\right)\right]_{\lambda}^{\infty}\\
&=\tau\left(\lambda^2-2\lambda\tau+2\tau^2\right)+\tau\left(\lambda^2+2\lambda\tau+2\tau^2\right)\\
&=4\tau^3+2\tau\lambda^2\\
&=4\tau^3+2\tau(\nu-\mu)^2.
\end{align*}
The antiderivatives you can get from integration by-parts.

Comment: just for anyone coming from Google with a short attention span like myself: *this is not the cross-entropy*; to get that divide this expression by $-\tau$ (which was omitted by OP presumably to simply the integral). And remember to divide by of twice the variance of the normal too.