# What is the entropy of multivariate data multiplied by a vector?

Tags: entropy, information-theory, multivariate-distribution, random-vector, vector

It is a general rule that for multivariate data $\boldsymbol{X}$ and a matrix $\boldsymbol{A}$, their entropy is

$$h(\boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{X}) = h(\boldsymbol{X}) + \ln |\det \boldsymbol{A}|$$
(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy#Properties_of_differential_entropy).

What is the rule for the entropy of $\boldsymbol{X}$ multiplied by a vector $\boldsymbol{b}$?

$$ h(\boldsymbol{X} \boldsymbol{b} ) = ?$$

Comment: Emulate the analysis given at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/415435.  It's unclear what you mean by your "also" question, since all of this is explicitly about distributions.

Comment: thanks, edited the last part. the question here is what the non-reduced entropy solution is of multiplying a multivariate dataset by a vector of weights, each corresponding to a univariate component of the multivariate. Not about the effect of shift or scale. Your link is all about univariate entropy only

Comment: The rule you linked assumes X is a random vector, not a random matrix. So, by Xb, do you mean the inner product of X and b?

Comment: My link is about *how to work with entropy.*  The method there extends, with no essential change, to multivariate problems.