# Does the output of a binary classification model equal to the probability of a positive outcome?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, classification, binary-data

Assuming you have a binary classification model $M$ i.e. that for an input $x$ it outputs a number $M(x)=\hat{y}$ where $\hat{y}\in[0,1]$ predicting the binary label of $y\in\{0,1\}$.

For example, a model that receives an image $x$ and outputs whether $x$ has a cat in it or not.

If such a model $M$ has high AUC-ROC (0.9+) for a large test dataset of $X$ and $Y$, does that mean that $\hat{y}$ is, in some way, the probability for $y=1$, (or $P(y=1)=\hat{y}$)?

Are there any resources (articles, books, etc.) regarding the relationaship between $P(y=1)$ and $\hat{y}$?

This question touchs the basics of classification models, and yet I couldn't find any good resources about the subject.

#### UPDATE:

What helped me better understand the classification vs probability subject is [probability calibration](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html) which is measured by a metric called [expected calibration error](https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classification/calibration_error.html).
[image]

Comment: The boundary here is between probabilistic modeling and decision theory. It's common for ML folks to decide that `y=1` when `P(y=1) > threshold`, though on this site we seem to agree that thresholding is bad for probabilistic modeling.

Comment: This gets at model calibration, but even if the AUC is low, it is reasonable to say that $\hat y$ is your best estimate of $P(y = 1\vert\text{data})$.

Comment: You can use math formatting via MathJax. More information: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I am not quite sure what are your assumptions, but you could have same AUC with monotonic increasing transformation of your probability estimate ( eg sqrt)

Comment: @Sycorax, thanks, I didn't see the $$ trick anywhere in the tips above the question text box... it is very useful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**YES AND NO**

**FIRST THE YES**

In theory, this is true. Start with logistic regression. That explicitly models the log-odds, which you can convert to the probability. A neural network with a `sigmoid` activation function on the final node is behaving the same as the inverse link function in a logistic regression. You're trying to get the probability.

**NOW THE NO**

Many machine learning models have poor calibration. The `sklearn` documentation has [some nice discussion of this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html). I also have an [open question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/532813/247274) about machine learning (particularly neural network) overconfidence. If your model has poor calibration, then it isn't really reasonable to claim that $\hat y_i= p$ means that $P(Y=1) = p$, since the model is, in some sense, not telling the truth.

Comment: Fantastic reference to the scikit-learn doc, it had very good references too. Accepted!

Comment: As an additional point (+1), it's also possible that $\hat y$ is not in $[0,1]$ and so can't be a probability. You might argue that something of this sort shouldn't be called a binary response model, I suppose