# Probability in a classification problem

Tags: machine-learning, probability, classification, conv-neural-network

In a classification problem (let's say of two categories, cat and dog) with a softmax output, does the probability have any physical meaning other than assigning the category to the input based on the higher probability? Putting another way: Can I say that there is X% probability of the input being a cat and Y% that the input is a dog? Of course, X+Y = 100%.

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/550549/247274)

Comment: Are you asking if a probability is a probability?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, though to be a little more precise, in this case X% is the probability of being a dog (and 100-X% is the probability of being a cat) *according to the model*. Models can be very wrong and different models will assign different probabilities.

Comment: I would call it "current belief", because by itself, it's not really a probability IMHO

Comment: Thanks. How would you interpret it otherwise?

Comment: @Shaz If you are asking Alberto, you can tag him by typing @ before his username (typed with no spaces), as I have done with yours at the beginning of this comment.

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia it is absolutely a probability. The fact that it might be wrong/miscalibrated does not change that

Comment: @Firebug if softmax indeed is a categorical distribution, you cannot say that it's the true $p(y|x)$, and you can see this from the fact that it can be badly calibrated https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.04599.pdf and temperatures can vary your output significantly... my point is not that the output of a softmax is not a distribution, indeed it is, form a mathematical perspective, but it's not the one that most of people would imagine ($p(y|x)$)

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Your interpretation would seem to exclude Bayesian probability, among other things. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_probability & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_interpretations