# Effect on entropy when we scale Bernoulli plus Gaussian

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, entropy, information-theory, inequality

**Question:** Given $X\sim\text{Bernoulli}(\alpha)$, $Y\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, and non-random positive constants $C,\epsilon>0$. Let $H(\cdot)$ be the differential entropy. Is it true that
$$
H((C+\epsilon)X+Y)>H(CX+Y),
$$
and is there a rigorous way to show this?

**Attempt:** Intuitively I suspect this to be true since from [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/415435/how-does-entropy-depend-on-location-and-scale), we know that scaling a random variable $W:=CX+Y$ introduces an additive factor. The issue here is that we are technically only (up)scaling a part of $W$ instead of the entire $W$.

If we are to think of $W$ as a mixture of two Gaussians, then the $\epsilon X$ additive component is akin to shifting on of the Gaussians.