Why is formalism of max entropy principle for continuous case different from discrete case?
In discrete case (Chapter 11 of Jaynes' Probability Theory: The Logic of Science), max entropy principle states that we need to encode our ignorance prior by doing a constrained optimization problem, which maximizes entropy $H=\sum_ip_i\log p_i$ subject to constraints $F_1, F_2, \dotsc$.
But when it comes to continuous case, we would need to consider issues related to transformation groups (Chapter 12 of the book), which I do not quite understand.  Why can't we just generalize discrete case to the continuous case, that is, maximizes entropy $H=\int dx\ p(x)\log p(x)$ subject to constraints $F_1(x), F_2(x), \dotsc$?  What is fundamentally different between discrete and continuous cases?

There are many reasons.  One of them is made clear at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/415435, which discusses a property of differential entropy (namely, how it changes under the action of a transformation group) that is irrelevant to entropy (because it is unaffected by any such action).
